# Error when converting int to numpy array?

Tags: numpy

I encounter the following errors when converting an integer to a numpy array:

```
a = 150
b = np.array(a)
b[0]
*** IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

I expect the output of  `b[0]` is `150`, but get the IndexError. Why?

Comment: the shape of your array is `()`. you can use `np.array([a])` if you want to define a one dimentional array.

Comment: Yes. And I don't understand the output of `b` is `array(150)` instead of `array([150])`. What does it mean?

Comment: notice that the output is based on the input shape. when you pass an scalar like 150, it's reasonable for output that have a dimensional of 0. by the way you can use indexing like `b[()]`.

Comment: `b[()]` indexes the 0d array with a 0 element tuple.  `np.array([150])[0]` indexes with a 1d array with 1 index.  `b.item()` is another way of getting the element (from either).

Answer (score 2):

You have in effect created a scalar or zero dimensional array.

If you need to index into this, try

```
b = np.array([a])
```